# Android why it does not work when I get the value in string.xml using the values getted from file

Tags: android

I want to know where is the problem right here :
    when I use a specific string like "tex1" it work perfectly,
     but when I get the string name that I kept from file it does not work
     besides that the string d getted from file is correct !

```
 idText=getResources().getIdentifier("tex1","string",getPackageName());
 Toast.makeText(this,"Le texte est "+getString(idText),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



 idText=getResources().getIdentifier(d,"string",getPackageName());
 Toast.makeText(this,"Le texte est  "+getString(idText),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Does not work!!!!!
```

Comment: I found that the problem was on the file that I extract data from i correct it  to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getString` like that :

Define the string you nedd in your file, with a name and a value

**string.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="my_text">My outstanding tex</string>
</resources>
```

then in your code

```
String myText = getString(R.string.my_text)
```

Concerning `getIdentifier` according the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier)

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient
>   to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but once I get the id I want to get string : when I use a specific value like "name_of_string" to get a id  it works the proplem is when I get ""name_of_string" from a file

Comment: How get you the name from the file ?

Comment: using this method : it's toot long how can show it to u?

Comment: here is the link to the methode : https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B2C_ujzkaPx8bnB2R0M2cm1NSk0